# how to add compaign parameter to flurry's banner

Tags: android, flurry

I'm thinking using flurry to promote my android app. It seems that flurry can put my app's ad as banner on other apps. My question is how can I append campaign parameter on the url on banner so that I can know something about the source. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Flurry, you can set a re-direct URL for cost-per-click (CPC) and cost-per-completed view (CPCV) promotional campaigns. However, if you're running a cost-per-install (CPI) campaign, you need to provide a direct AppStore link. In case you're looking to monitor the performance of various acquisition channels, you can refer to the new [User Acquisition Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-user-acquisition-analytics.html) feature offered by Flurry.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)